# What can be used within individual workbenches to produce the right output? - ISTQB question

Tags: tools, techniques, standards, istqb

I have found the following question in an ISTQB Foundation Level exam [sample paper](http://www.softwaretestingstuff.com/2008/11/istqb-sample-question-paper-4.html).

Q13. ________ and ________ are used within individual workbenches to produce the right output products.

- A. Tools and techniques
- B. Procedures and standards
- C. Processes and walkthroughs
- D. Reviews and update

The correct answer is given as **B. Procedures and standards**

But my belief is that both **A & B are correct** because Tools, Techniques, Procedures as well as Standards can be used by an individual employee who works in their own workbench.

Can anyone think of a particular reason why only the answer **B** is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tools and techniques** allow you to test in a specific way (depending on the tool, or on which technique used).

They will produce *correct output* (as in: the product has been verified correctly by using such a tool/technique).

**Procedures and standards** make sure every individual will test in a similar manner (regardless of which tools/technique is used - or even better: guiding the individual to use specific techniques).

They will produce the correct *output products* (as in, for example: test management wants certain reports on certain types of tests run; audit needs to have a paper trail on tests executed in a conform manner, ...)